# Using .resemple() in python to go from weekly to monthly time series

Tags: python, pandas-resample

Is it possible to use .resample() to take the last observation in a month of a weekly time series to create a monthly time series from the weekly time series?  I don't want to sum or average anything, just take the last observation of each month
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you want and what the documentation describes, you could try the following :

```py
data[COLUMN].resample('M', convention='end')
```

Try it out and update us!

**References**
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html

Answer (score 0):

Is the 'week' field as week of year, a date  or other?

If it's a datetime, and you have datetime library imported , use  .dt.to_period('M')   on your current date column to create a new 'month' column, then get  the max date for each month to get the date to sample  ( if you only want the LAST date  in each month ? )

Like max(df['MyDateField'])

Someone else is posting as I type this, so may have a better answer :)